# Recommendations and Polls

Tags: discussion, faq, questions, asking-questions

Some questions:

- Why are recommendations, and polls off-topic?
- How can I delineate whether a question should be closed because it is related to being a recommendation or poll?
- Is there an on-topic way to rephrase these kind of recommendation requests?
- Is there a [Network Engineering](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/) resource we can use for polls or product recommendations?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### > Why are recommendations or polls off-topic?

Stack Exchange strives to be an [authoritative resource for Questions and Answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/75940/160519).  Polls and recommendations wind up being a [Repository (of knowledge)](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/997/handling-game-recommendations-how-can-we-solve-these-two-problems-of-quality), which is fundamentally at odds with the structure of [SE](http://stackexchange.com/).

Also note that [shopping questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) are a subset of recommendations (i.e. someone is asking for a product recommendation).

Fundamentally, we're drawing the same line between good and bad subjective questions that [Jeff Atwood did years ago after he started Stack Overflow](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/).

---

#### > How can I delineate whether a question should be closed because it is related to being a recommendation or poll?

This is a bit subjective, but I usually look at the question and ask myself, "Can anyone give a *wrong* answer to this question?"  If there is *no wrong answer* (within reason), then the question needs to be closed.

Examples of questions with no wrong answer:

- What router / switch / firewall should I buy for this project?
- Which service provider should I use in Central London?
- What tools exist for QoS testing?
- Can someone recommend a hyperlink, book or paper for `<insert-topic-here>`?
- Can someone recommend a resource or library for python scripting Cisco routers?
- What kind of interview questions would you ask when you're talking to a Senior Network Engineer candidate?

In the cases above, you can see that there could be many different valid answers to those questions.

---

#### > Is there an on-topic way to rephrase these kind of recommendations?

[Sometimes there is](https://meta.superuser.com/a/5373/77053). (Note to self, some day improve this to be more specific to network engineering).

Some guidelines (shamelessly copying from [Jeff Atwood's blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/))...

http://blog.stackoverflow.com/wp-content/uploads/screenshot-0.png

1. *Great subjective questions inspire answers that explain “why” and “how”.* The best subjective questions invite explanation.
2. *Great subjective questions tend to have long, not short, answers*. The best subjective questions inspire your peers to share their actual experiences.
3. *Great subjective questions have a constructive, fair, and impartial tone.* The best subjective questions avoid the all too seductive route of ranting and flamebait.
4. *Great subjective questions invite sharing experiences over opinions.* Certainly experiences inform opinions, but the best subjective questions unabashedly and unashamedly prioritize sharing actual experiences over random opinions.
5. *Great subjective questions insist that opinion be backed up with facts and references.* Opinion isn’t all bad, so long as it’s backed up with something other than “because I’m an expert”, or “because I said so”, or “just because”.
6. *Great subjective questions are more than just mindless social fun.*

---

#### > Is there a *Network Engineering* resource we can use when discussing subjective questions, such as product recommendations?

Yes, polls and recommendations are very welcome in the **[Network Engineering Recommendations Chat Room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11177/general-network-engineering-recommendations)**.

A few rules in this chat room, please:

- This chat room is *not* a substitute for asking on-topic [Network Engineering](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/) questions
- This chat room is *not* for live support (which of course is on-topic for the main site)
- It's the same [behavior](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/help/behavior) we expect everywhere.  Be honest. Be nice. Don't promote your products or spam us.