# Is it off-topic? Discussion of Open Source Alternatives to a Commercial Product

Tags: discussion, off-topic

I want to hear ideas on how we can replace a commercial product with a set of open source alternatives however this will involve many features of a commercial product. Would this be off-topic?

Answer (score 2):

> I want to hear ideas on how we can replace a commercial product with a set of open source alternatives however this will involve many features of a commercial product. Would this be off-topic?

Questions like this fall into the category of [recommendations / polls](https://networkengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/255/recommendations-and-polls/256#256), which only have one real home in the stack exchange network.

Please ask on [software recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Recommendation of products or resources is off-topic. I think a question about the features of a specific open-source network product, assuming the question isn't too broad and is truly a network product, not an application, could be on-topic.